# Json deserialising using GSON

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, gson

I'm using Gson to deserialize Json into my custom class but when I try to do it an exception was caused.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace declares multiple JSON fields named serialVersionUID
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar!/:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar!/:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar!/:?]
```

I'm using the following code:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
MyClass data = gson.fromJson(json, MyClass.class);
```

My class looks like the following:

```
public class MyClass {
    public String name;
    public int age;
}
```

Json:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": 25
}
```

I can't modify the `java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace` class and I don't understand why it happened.
I'm using `java11` and `gson-2.8.6`.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you provide your JSON and class you wanna deserialize?

Comment: @DoanVanThang I added the class and JSON.

Comment: Hope you have escaped “ in you json string, in case you have hardcoded json string in your code? Other than this I don’t find any issue here.

Comment: @John The class you provided is _clean_ and does not contain any reference to `ICC_ColorSpace`. It survives both to-JSON and from-JSON round trip even being non-static inner class. You class must have had a reference to `ICC_ColorSpace` directly on indirectly. Please provide the full class. Or are you really sure the exception is encountered in the place you mentioned in the question?

Comment: Additionally I doubt you'll be able to serialize/deserialize `ICC_ColorSpace` (if you're really doing it, at least Gson exception tells so) safely in a robust way for different versions of Java.

Comment: Weird, your json and class works normally on me `java13` latest gson.